# How to assign a Button to processOnClick?

Tags: android, process, flashlight

the code with the process is not the best, or it's too complicated for enabling Camera.
i desided to change to something easyer.
this is it

```
package app.technozed.androlighter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean flashlightOn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    flashlightOn = false;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button onbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onbut);
    //Button offbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.offbut);

    onbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    Camera cam;
    cam = Camera.open(); 

    if (flashlightOn == false) {    
        Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(p);
        cam.startPreview();
        flashlightOn = true;
    } else {
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
        flashlightOn=false;
    }
}
    });
}
}
```

but now i'm getting the java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21183): Process: app.technozed.androlighter, PID: 21183
E/AndroidRuntime(21183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:350)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:324)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at app.technozed.androlighter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(21183):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my Manifest:

```
 <!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
    <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

what is wrong here? i had this error before, and it was about Manifest permission's ... but what about now?

Answer (score 2):

In your class

```
    private boolean mIsOn;
```

And inside onCreate

```
    onoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mIsOn) {
                processOffClick();
                mIsOn = false;
            } else {
                processOnClick();
                mIsOn = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Beat me by few minutes ;) +1 from me

Comment: Thanks melquiades I got you covered ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set a global flag that will indicate whether flash is on or off, say:

   ```
   private boolean flashIsOn;
   ```
2. If successfully enabled flash, set the flag to true, somewhere in processOnClick()

   ```
   flashIsOn = true;
   ```
3. If successfully disabled flash, set the flag to false, somewhere in processOffClick()

   ```
   flashIsOn = false;
   ```
4. Now, assign OnClickListener to your button and call the appropriate function based on flag state:

   ```
   onoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           if (flashIsOn) {
               processOffClick();
           } else {
               processOnClick();  
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use your code like this

```
onoff.setOnClickListener(new   OnClickListener()

{
  @Override
  public   void   onClick(View   v) 
     {

     //here you write the code

     }
});
```

for you to make it easier to understand and to write I recommend that you write an if statement, what I mean by that is that you write an if statement that simply checks if the led light is on ---> turn it off, and if the led light is on ---> turn it off, and that code should be written in the `onClick()` method.

Hope I could help :)

If I did please let me know :)

Comment: hey, so now i'm using your concept, but i got a runtime error, can you take a look please. Thanks

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the button you created it says

`Fail to connect to camera service`

the error explains it self, are you testing your app through your phone or through an Android Virtual Device?

Comment: Phone with a LED lamp